# Javascript convert object key names based on mapping

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object that is coming from `Source1` and I am unable to change its native structure or naming convention. I am using this data to feed into a 3rd party plugin to generate some chart data. This plugin however is using the key names as the identifiers on the chart and they are not descriptive or clear enough.

I am trying to run the object through a conversion function where it will change all of the key names to their defined equivalent.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
var obj = [{
  SubmissionID: "28935",
  MetaCreatedDate: "12 Mar 2018",
  Program: "Brand Risk Management",
  ViewedByInvestigator: "No",
},
{
  SubmissionID: "28936",
  MetaCreatedDate: "12 Mar 2018",
  Program: "Brand Risk Management",
  ViewedByInvestigator: "Yes",
}]

function convertNames(obj){

  // Converted names
    var map = [{
    SubmissionID: 'SubmissionIdentifier',
    MetaCreatedDate: 'CreationDate',
    Program: 'ProgramName',
    ViewedByInvestigator: 'Viewed'
  }];

  // Loop through the object and convert all key names to their equivalent

  for(var prop in obj){
    // Convert Here

    }

  return obj;
}
```

Desired Output:

```
[{
  SubmissionIdentifier: "28935",
  CreationDate: "12 Mar 2018",
  ProgramName: "Brand Risk Management",
  Viewed: "No",
},
{
  SubmissionIdentifier: "28936",
  CreationDate: "12 Mar 2018",
  ProgramName: "Brand Risk Management",
  Viewed: "Yes",
}]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hbg4sfqh/7/

Comment: Have you tried anything? You might look into "bracket notation" for a starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd combine the `.map` array method and a function to convert your key names to get the result you want. To convert the key names, you'll want to use bracket notation, so something like: `newObj[keyMap[oldKey]] = oldObj[oldKey]` should work.

Here's a simple implementation for your example:

```js
const obj = [{
  SubmissionID: "28935",
  MetaCreatedDate: "12 Mar 2018",
  Program: "Brand Risk Management",
  ViewedByInvestigator: "No",
}, {
  SubmissionID: "28936",
  MetaCreatedDate: "12 Mar 2018",
  Program: "Brand Risk Management",
  ViewedByInvestigator: "Yes",
}];

const nameMap = {
  SubmissionID: 'SubmissionIdentifier',
  MetaCreatedDate: 'CreationDate',
  Program: 'ProgramName',
  ViewedByInvestigator: 'Viewed'
}

function renameKeys(obj, map) {
    const newObj = {};
    for (let key in obj) {
        newObj[map[key]] = obj[key];
    }
    
    return newObj;
}

console.log(obj.map(item => renameKeys(item, nameMap)));
```

I'd also note that if you happen to be using the lodash library, you can also use it's `_.mapKeys` method to do this.

Comment: This seems to work but IE 10 is throwing a syntax error on this line `data = data.map(item => renameKeys(item, nameMap));`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Arrow syntax is es6+ so try using the old function syntax, eg: `data = data.map(function(item) { return renameKeys(item, nameMap) })`. However the `map` method may also not be supported everywhere, so if that's the case, you'll need to polyfill it or just use a plain for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna use .map() function to change the key names. The input data will remain unchanged. Hope this helps.

```js
var obj = [{
  SubmissionID: "28935",
  MetaCreatedDate: "12 Mar 2018",
  Program: "Brand Risk Management",
  ViewedByInvestigator: "No",
},
{
  SubmissionID: "28936",
  MetaCreatedDate: "12 Mar 2018",
  Program: "Brand Risk Management",
  ViewedByInvestigator: "Yes",
}]

var output = obj.map(element => ({
  SubmissionIdentifier: element.SubmissionID,
  CreationDate: element.MetaCreatedDate,
  ProgramName: element.Program,
  Viewed: element.ViewedByInvestigator
}));
```